# Find Solutions For Second Order Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find General Solution for
>   $$y''+4y'+5y=0$$$$b^2-4c< 0$$
>   $$y_1=e^\frac{-bx}{2}\cos \frac{\sqrt{4c-b^2}}{2}x$$
>   $$y_2=e^\frac{-bx}{2}\sin \frac{\sqrt{4c-b^2}}{2}x$$
>   Given following, find solutions for which
>   $$y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$$
>   $$y(0)=12,y'(0)=-5$$
>   $$y_1=e^\frac{-4x}{2}\cos \frac{\sqrt{20-16}}{2}x$$
>   $$y_2=e^\frac{-4x}{2}\sin \frac{\sqrt{20-16}}{2}x$$
>   $$y_1=e^{-2x}\cos x$$
>   $$y_2=e^{-2x}\sin x$$
>   But where to from here?

Comment: Please clarify the question a bit.. Do you need to find two solutions with the initial conditions at the first two equations in the second part, given the two solutions at the end?

Comment: Glue the two functions together than find appropriate constants.

Comment: @Nescio - I believe the answer is yes, I mainly need to know if my algebra was correct.

Comment: If f is a solution to the above differential equation then it must satisfy the differential equation. If another function g is also a solution then it must also meet the condition. We can write them as a linear combination as the general solution. That is $y=c_1f+c_2g$  It seems counter-intuitive. Consider the following differential equation. Eg $|\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}|-y=0$  We know that both transcendental function sin x & cos x satisfy it but there is more like $e^x$ we can write them as a linear combination which is $y=c_1sinx+c_2cosx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y′′+4y′+5y=0$$

Take auxiliary equation,

let 
$$y=e^{mx}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=me^{mx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=m^2e^{mx}$$

Substituting into the differential equation we obtain

$$m^2e^{mx}+4me^{mx}+5e^{mx}=0$$ provided $$e^{mx} \neq0$$

$$m^2+4m+5=0$$

Solving it using quadratic formula we have

$$m=-2\pm i$$

The solution is then

$$y=e^{-2x}[c_1cosx+c_2sinx]$$

Given $$y(0)=1$$

$$c_1=1$$

Also,

$$y'=-2e^{-2x}[c_1cosx+c_2sinx]+e^{-2x}[-c_1sinx+c_2cosx]$$

$$y'(0)=0$$

$$c_2-2c_1=0$$
$$c_2=2$$

The particular solution is then

$$y=e^{-2x}[cosx+2sinx]$$

Addendum

Clarification of complex root

We know that complex number takes the form of

$$z=a+bi$$

Taking exponential on both sides we have

$$e^z=e^{a+bi}$$

Recall that

$$e^{a+b}=e^a.e^b$$

Taking out a we have

$$e^{zx}=e^{ax}.e^{bxi}$$

Euler's equation of complex number is

$$e^{i \theta}=cos\theta+isin\theta$$

Replacing $\theta$ with $bx$

So we have,

$$e^{ax}.e^{bxi}=e^{ax}cosbx+isinbx$$

Recall the the solution for complex roots also contain its conjugate that is 
$$z_1=a+bi$$
$$z_2=a-bi$$

So the general solution is

$$y=k_1e^{(a+bi)x}+k_2e^{(a-bi)x}$$

Factoring out $e^{ax}$

$$y=e^{ax}[k_1e^{bix}+k_2e^{-bix}]$$

$$y=e^{ax}[k_1{cosx+sinx}+k_2{cosx-sinx}]$$

$$y=e^{ax}[k_1cosx+k_2cosx+k-1sinx-k_2sinx]$$

let $k_1+k_2=c_1$ and $k_1-k_2=c_2$

$$y=e^{ax}[c_1cosx+c_2sinx]$$

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $y''+4y'+5y=0$ is given by

$y(x)=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)$,

($c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb R$), with the functions $y_1,y_2$ from above.

Now determine $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$